# RSA_private_decrypt crashes when called for the second time

Tags: c++, objective-c, openssl, rsa, objective-c++

Please take a look at the following method:

```
int BCVirtualCard::decrypt(std::string from, std::string *to, int keyId, bool padding)
{
    if (to == nullptr)
    {
        NSCAssert(NO, @"Invalid params");
        return 0;
    }

    NSString* privateKey            = [m_storage privateKeyForSlot:keyId];
    NSArray<NSString*>* components  = [privateKey componentsSeparatedByString:@"_"];
    const NSInteger componentsCount = 4;

    if (components.count != componentsCount)
    {
        *to = "";
        return 0;
    }

    const char* d = [components[0] UTF8String];
    const char* n = [components[1] UTF8String];
    const char* p = [components[2] UTF8String];
    const char* q = [components[3] UTF8String];

    RSA* rsa = RSA_new();

    BN_hex2bn(&rsa->d, d);
    BN_hex2bn(&rsa->n, n);
    BN_hex2bn(&rsa->p, p);
    BN_hex2bn(&rsa->q, q);

    unsigned char* _to = (unsigned char *)calloc(1, sizeof(unsigned char));

    int decryptedSize = RSA_private_decrypt((int)from.length(), (unsigned char *)from.c_str(), _to, rsa, RSA_NO_PADDING);

    free(_to);

    if (decryptedSize <= 0)
    {
        ERR_print_errors_cb(test, NULL);

        *to = "";
        return 0;
    }

    _to = (unsigned char *)calloc(decryptedSize, sizeof(unsigned char));

    RSA_private_decrypt((int)from.length(), (unsigned char *)from.c_str(), _to, rsa, RSA_NO_PADDING);

    *to = std::string((char *)_to, strlen((char *)_to));

    free(_to);

    RSA_free(rsa);

    return 1;
}
```

Here the string `from` is supposed to be decrypted and written to the string `to`. For decryption I use `RSA_private_decrypt` function. I call it two times. First time in order to determine the size of the decrypted text and second time in order to write the decrypted text into `_to` buffer. And when I call it second time it usually crashes like this:

```
malloc: Heap corruption detected, free list is damaged at 0x280ff3d70
*** Incorrect guard value: 0
No1BCmail(2171,0x170efb000) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

The breakpoint is on and this let me find the place of the crash. However I can't understand the reason why it crashes. I tried recreating the `RSA` structure and playing with the size allocated for `_to` for the second time, but nothing helps. Can you see what is wrong here? Thanks

Comment: Is `_to` actually null terminated?  If not you should be using `*to = std::string((char *)_to, decryptedSize);`

Comment: Also, per [this](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/RSA_private_decrypt.html), your first call to decrypt is UB: *`to` must point to a memory section large enough to hold the decrypted data (which is smaller than RSA_size(rsa)).*

Comment: @NathanOliver As for your second comment - this is the whole reason why I am calling RSA_private_decrypt two times. I simply don't know the size that I should allocate for _to buffer. I need to get it first. do you see?

Comment: Looks like using `RSA_size(rsa)` should give you a buffer size to use.  It gets that value from `rsa->n`.  So you could do `unsigned char* _to = new unsigned char[RSA_size(rsa)]; ...; delete _to`.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm not really good at RSA. Do you mean that the size of the decrypted text will always be less or equal than n? Right?

Comment: From my first time casual perusal of the documentation, that was the assumption I made.  You'll have to wait for someone who actually knows though for a real answer.  I just figured I'd lend a fresh set of eyes and see if it might be something that was overlooked.

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks for your help

Comment: @NathanOliver your comment helped me to get rid of the crash. It is gone. I'm not sure by now whether I should remove the second call to RSA_private_decrypt or not, but the crash is fixed. You can post the comment as answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RSA_private_decrypt` requires that the `to` parameter points to a buffer of an adequate size.  Your first call only uses a buffer of size 1, which is too small and is undefined behavior.  What you need to do is get the size from `rsa` using `RSA_size(rsa)`, and then you can use that to allocate space for `_to`.  That means you don't need to call the function twice, since you'll already have the size the first time around

You should also be using `decryptedSize` for the length if the string to build instead of using `strlen` as `_to` may not be null terminated.

Putting all that together you could should look something like

```
int BCVirtualCard::decrypt(std::string from, std::string *to, int keyId, bool padding)
{
    if (to == nullptr)
    {
        NSCAssert(NO, @"Invalid params");
        return 0;
    }

    NSString* privateKey            = [m_storage privateKeyForSlot:keyId];
    NSArray<NSString*>* components  = [privateKey componentsSeparatedByString:@"_"];
    const NSInteger componentsCount = 4;

    if (components.count != componentsCount)
    {
        *to = "";
        return 0;
    }

    const char* d = [components[0] UTF8String];
    const char* n = [components[1] UTF8String];
    const char* p = [components[2] UTF8String];
    const char* q = [components[3] UTF8String];

    RSA* rsa = RSA_new();

    BN_hex2bn(&rsa->d, d);
    BN_hex2bn(&rsa->n, n);
    BN_hex2bn(&rsa->p, p);
    BN_hex2bn(&rsa->q, q);

    auto _to = std::make_unique<unsigned char[]>(RSA_size(rsa)); // use smart pointers so you don't have to worry about releasing the memory

    int decryptedSize = RSA_private_decrypt((int)from.length(), (unsigned char *)from.c_str(), _to.get(), rsa, RSA_NO_PADDING);

    if (decryptedSize <= 0)
    {
        ERR_print_errors_cb(test, NULL);    
        *to = "";
        return 0;
    }

    *to = std::string((char *)_to.get(), decryptedSize);
    return 1;
}
```